# Converting characters into variable names

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

`exec_parties2` is a data frame withe the following 12 variables:

"CE" "DB" "ES" "FC" "FF" "HF" "HR" "JE" "JF" "JR" "SE" "SR"

I want to create a loop that ranks each variable

This is an working example for the first variable:

```
exec_parties2<-exec_parties2 %>% mutate(CE_T=eval(dense_rank(CE)))
```

I was trying something like this:

```
r<-colnames(exec_parties2)

i=1

for(i in r){

  exec_parties3<-exec_parties2 %>% mutate(eval(r[i])=dense_rank(desc(r[i])))   

}
```

Obviously, it is not working

I know this is doable and it should be documented somewhere. I just cant't find it. This is similar to a macro in SAS (a program that writes code).

Apologies for the silly question and thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Try `mutate(!! r[i] := dense_rank(desc(!! rlang::sym(r[i])))`

Comment: It’s documented here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: Do you want to create a *new* column with a different name, or mutate an existing column? If the latter, use `mutate_at` instead of rlang.

Comment: `mutate_at()` can be pretty convenient for this sort of thing.  And you can even make  new names.  Like `mutate_at(exec_parties2, r, list(T = ~dense_rank(desc(.) ) ) )`

Comment: I wasn't aware that dplyr quotes ALL inputs. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current `for` loop, we can do an assignment (`:=`) within `mutate` by evaluating (`!!`) while converting the string column name to symbol (`sym`) and evaluate (`!!`)

```
r <- colnames(exec_parties2)
for(nm in r) {

    exec_parties2 <- exec_parties2 %>% 
                          mutate(!! nm := dense_rank(desc(!! rlang::sym(nm))))
  }
```

NOTE: As in the comments, this can be done much easily with `mutate_at`

Comment: A bracket is missing from the mutate statement. THANKS!. I wanted a new variable so I did: `mutate(!! paste0(nm,"_r") := dense_rank(desc(!! rlang::sym(nm))))`. I added the suffix "_r". THANKS!!!!!